# Don't duplicate Interface in implemented class

Tags: typescript

I have interface like that

```
interface IAroma {
title: string,
title_description: string,
brand: string,
since: string,
sex: string,
country: string,
collection: string,
composition: IComposition,
description: string,
similar: string[],
slug: string,
images: string[],
}
```

And I want to have class implements from that Interface like that:

```
class Aroma implements IAroma{
    title: string
    title_description: string
    brand: string
    since: string
    sex: string
    country: string
    collection: string
    composition: IComposition
    description: string
    similar: string[]
    slug: string
    images: string[]
    constructor($: CheerioStatic, slug: string) {
        this.title = ...
        this.title_description = ...
        this.brand = ...
        this.since = ...
        this.sex = ...
        this.country = ...
        this.collection = ...
        this.description = ...
        this.similar = ...
        this.slug = slug
        this.images = ...
        this.composition = ...
    }
}
```

I will need this Interface in other places of my code. Can I don't duplicate properties in class? 
Or I should not use Interface at all and just use class?